# postback not auto filling in with php array data

Tags: php, arrays, http, postback

this page has a section for editing multiple rows of "child" data within a parent page.
[image: screenshot-editchild]

the "UPDATE" button successfully sends the data through a php array into the postback event, which we successfully receive and are able to update the database.

The only problem is that the form reverts back to showing the original data.  I suspect I am doing something wrong with the variables and they are somehow not the same variable, but I'm not really sure. Can anyone spot my mistake?

```
<?php
require 'myheader.php'; // includes my db connection info
echo "<h2>Edit Children</h2>";
/*
this uses a multiline edit table to edit child info in place
and delete row buttons and and add button
*/
// initialize the child vars
$childid = '';
$subscribed = '';
$surname = '';
$firstname = '';
$commonname = '';
$othernames = '';
$dob = '';

// get the PARENT id from the session
$personid = $_SESSION['personid'];

if($personid === ""){
    echo "Please select a member first<br>";
}else{
    // Display the page
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }    
    echo "<hr><b>Member</b>";
    $sqldemographics = "select personid, active, gender, dob, surname, firstname, commonname, othernames from members where personid = '" . $personid . "'";
    //echo $sqldemographics . "<br>";
    $demographics = $conn->query($sqldemographics);
    if ($demographics->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><td><b>Surname</b></td><td><b>Common Name</b></td><td><b>First Name</b></td><td><b>Other Names</b></td><td><b>Date of Birth</b></td></tr>"; 
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $demographics->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['commonname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['othernames'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['dob'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";  
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "Unable to find matching member with personid: " . $personid . "<br>";
    }
    // done with MEMBER stuff

    // -------  Move on to CHILD stuff  ------------------------
    echo "<hr><b>Children</b>";
    $sqlchildren = "select * from children inner join guardians on guardians.childid = children.childid where guardians.personid = '" . $personid . "'";
    $children = $conn->query($sqlchildren);
    if ($children->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        // set up the form to display children AND allow edits
        echo "<form method='post' action='" . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "'>";
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><td><b>Subscribed</b></td><td><b>Surname</b></td><td><b>First Name</b></td><td><b>Common Name</b></td><td><b>Other Names</b></td><td><b>Date of Birth</b></td></tr>";
        while($row = $children->fetch_array()) {
            // use input arrays
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['issubscribed']."</td>"; // subscriptions is not editable on this page
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='surname[]' value='".$row['surname']."' maxlength='32' size='10' /></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='firstname[]' value='".$row['firstname']."' maxlength='32' size='10' /></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='commonname[]' value='".$row['commonname']."' maxlength='32' size='10' /></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='othernames[]' value='".$row['othernames']."' maxlength='32' size='10' /></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='dob[]' value='".$row['dob']."' maxlength='32' size='10' /></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='childid[]' value='".$row['childid']."' /></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "<input type='submit' name='update' value='UPDATE' />";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</form>";
    } else {
        echo "No associated child records found for " . $personname . "<br>";
    }

    echo "<a href='AddChild.php'>Add Children</a><br>";


    // ------ GET vs POST -----------------------------------------------
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"){
        // it's NOT a post back.

    }else{
        // it's a post back after editing child data into the form, so scrub and check the data
        // make sure it's the "update" button
        if(isset($_POST['update'])){
            // its (zero indexed) arrays of each COLUMN
            // since our algorithm is row based for the db insert it will have to explicitly index each array 

            // grab all the posted data into arrays
            $childid = $_POST['childid'];
            $subscribed = $_POST['subscribed'];
            $surname = $_POST['surname'];
            $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            $commonname = $_POST['commonname'];
            $othernames = $_POST['othernames'];
            $dob = $_POST['dob'];

            /*
            print_r($childid);
            echo "<br>";
            print_r($firstname); 
            echo "<br>";
            */

            // loop through the posted array of children
            $index = 0;
            foreach ($childid as $value => $ind_childid) {
                $ind_subscribed = $subscribed[$index];
                $ind_surname = $surname[$index];
                $ind_firstname = $firstname[$index];
                $ind_commonname = $commonname[$index];
                $ind_othernames = $othernames[$index];
                $ind_dob = $dob[$index];
                ++$index;           
                $sqlupdatechildren = "UPDATE children SET surname = '$ind_surname', firstname = '$ind_firstname', commonname = '$ind_commonname', othernames = '$ind_othernames', dob = '$ind_dob' WHERE childid = '$ind_childid'";
                echo "$sqlupdatechildren<br>";
                $conn->query($sqlupdatechildren); // insert the record          
            }   

            // !!! do we have to put the new data back into the form or something?

        } // end "update" button
    } // end postback section
    $conn->close();  //close database
}

require 'myfooter.php';
?>
```

---

thanks in advance
Ken

Comment: First of all where is session_start();

Comment: For what it's worth, if you used templating and/or an [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework, you'd likely have a far easier time following your own code.

Comment: devpro - good question . the session is started in the header file

Comment: Patrick - I'd be interested in finding out more about that - thanks for the MVC link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is querying the database and using the results to build the HTML output *before* detecting if a POST was done and updating the database. You need to turn the processing order around so that the POST processing is done first, and then the HTML output is generated last.

Comment: I think you are onto something Brian - I will try that

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of completion, here is the FIXED code:

```
<?php
require 'playgroundsheader.php';
echo "<h2>Edit Children</h2>";
/*
this uses a multiline edit table to edit child info in place
and delete row buttons and and add button
*/
// initialize the child vars
$childid = '';
$subscribed = '';
$surname = '';
$firstname = '';
$commonname = '';
$othernames = '';
$dob = '';

// get the PARENT id from the session
$personid = $_SESSION['personid'];

if($personid === ""){
    echo "Please select a member first<br>";
}else{
    // Display the page
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }    
    echo "<hr><b>Member</b>";
    $sqldemographics = "select personid, active, gender, dob, surname, firstname, commonname, othernames from members where personid = '" . $personid . "'";
    //echo $sqldemographics . "<br>";
    $demographics = $conn->query($sqldemographics);
    if ($demographics->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><td><b>Surname</b></td><td><b>Common Name</b></td><td><b>First Name</b></td><td><b>Other Names</b></td><td><b>Date of Birth</b></td></tr>"; 
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $demographics->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['commonname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['othernames'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['dob'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";  
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "Unable to find matching member with personid: " . $personid . "<br>";
    }
    // done with MEMBER stuff

    // -------  Move on to CHILD stuff  ------------------------

    // ------ GET vs POST -----------------------------------------------
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"){
        // it's NOT a post back.

    }else{
        // it's a post back after editing child data into the form, so scrub and check the data
        // make sure it's the "update" button
        if(isset($_POST['update'])){
            // its (zero indexed) arrays of each COLUMN
            // since our algorithm is row based for the db insert it will have to explicitly index each array 

            // grab all the posted data into arrays
            $childid = $_POST['childid'];
            $subscribed = $_POST['subscribed'];
            $surname = $_POST['surname'];
            $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
            $commonname = $_POST['commonname'];
            $othernames = $_POST['othernames'];
            $dob = $_POST['dob'];

            /*
            print_r($childid);
            echo "<br>";
            print_r($firstname); 
            echo "<br>";
            */

            // loop through the posted array of children
            $index = 0;
            foreach ($childid as $value => $ind_childid) {
                $ind_subscribed = $subscribed[$index];
                $ind_surname = $surname[$index];
                $ind_firstname = $firstname[$index];
                $ind_commonname = $commonname[$index];
                $ind_othernames = $othernames[$index];
                $ind_dob = $dob[$index];
                ++$index;           
                $sqlupdatechildren = "UPDATE children SET surname = '$ind_surname', firstname = '$ind_firstname', commonname = '$ind_commonname', othernames = '$ind_othernames', dob = '$ind_dob' WHERE childid = '$ind_childid'";
                //echo "$sqlupdatechildren<br>";
                $conn->query($sqlupdatechildren); // insert the record          
            }   
        } // end "update" button
    } // end postback section

    echo "<hr><b>Children</b>";
    $sqlchildren = "select * from children inner join guardians on guardians.childid = children.childid where guardians.personid = '" . $personid . "'";
    $children = $conn->query($sqlchildren);
    if ($children->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        // set up the form to display children AND allow edits
        echo "<form method='post' action='" . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "'>";
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><td><b>Subscribed</b></td><td><b>Surname</b></td><td><b>First Name</b></td><td><b>Common Name</b></td><td><b>Other Names</b></td><td><b>Date of Birth</b></td></tr>";
        while($row = $children->fetch_array()) {
            // use input arrays
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['issubscribed']."</td>"; // subscriptions is not editable on this page
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='surname[]' value='".$row['surname']."' maxlength='32' size='10' /></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='firstname[]' value='".$row['firstname']."' maxlength='32' size='10' /></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='commonname[]' value='".$row['commonname']."' maxlength='32' size='10' /></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='othernames[]' value='".$row['othernames']."' maxlength='32' size='10' /></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='text' name='dob[]' value='".$row['dob']."' maxlength='32' size='10' /></td>";
            echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='childid[]' value='".$row['childid']."' /></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "<input type='submit' name='update' value='UPDATE' />";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</form>";
    } else {
        echo "No associated child records found for " . $personname . "<br>";
    }
    // This part calls playgroundsAddChild.php
    echo "<a href='playgroundsAddChild.php'>Add Children</a><br>";

    $conn->close();  //close database
}
require 'playgroundsfooter.php';
?>
```